# How Hazelcast queries work when MapStore is specified?

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have hazelcast map that contains active sessions. I fully implemented MapStore which loads and stores documents from MongoDB.
Now I need execute distributed query to process all entries in the map but when Hazelcast evicts entries from the collection, persisted entries are not checking.

What the right way to process *all* entries in that way?

Do I need write two versions of the query for Hazelcast and for persisted entries in MongoDB?

May be there is configurable behavior for collection to make Hazelcast sync all entries in storage into the map?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast queries do not fetch anything from MapLoader. If you know the entries that got evicted (although I am not sure what real purpose would this serve as it contradicts the reason of using an in-memory cache in first place) then you can do a `getAll` on those keys before running the query. That will load those “missing” entries back into cache.

Comment: The real purpose is ability to close session if it was evicted from map and never loaded anymore. Closing session means create record in another storage. If I will use only Hz queries, evicted sessions will never be recorded to the storage. Otherwise, if I will query only storage wrapped by MapStore I also need query the Map to delete records. `getAll` supposes that I know keys but I dont.

Comment: You can use EntryExpiredListener and/or EntryEvictedListener and keep a record of all entries that were expired/evicted.